# Using ”text” datatype for storing password hash in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, server, passwords

No, this question is not a duplicate of the numerous ”What's the best MySQL datatype for storing passwords”.

My password hashes are currently made using pbkdfSync on node.js, and I have the output set to 128(Whatever bytes bits it is), and it's pushing out a 256 char hash.

You might ask what's the problem? Well, that's what I thought. **before I got hit with this: ”Value too long for column password” when using VARCHAR.**

Numerous google searches are saying that the varchar character limit is 65,535 characters, but for some reason for me **it is only 255** and the hash is one char bigger than that.

So the question here is: 
Should I change my hash output size, so I can use the CHAR datatype, or should I just keep using the TEXT datatype? Or is there a way to get the 65,535 characters limit for char and varchar?

I'm on the latest MySQL version.

Edit: There's more to this, I am encrypting the hashes and salts and the encrypted output is 512 chars for the hash and 344 for the salt!

Comment: So you want a password column with datatype VARCHAR(856) ?

Comment: @TGrif No, im using a separate column/entry for the hash. Is there a way to use varchar for more than 255 chars? Should i down my hashing function, or keep using text data type?

Comment: I guess @TGrif meant that you can change the type of you column to VARCHAR(856) which will allow you to store more than 255 chars (actually 856) in your column. Try something like this: `ALTER TABLE name_of_your_table CHANGE COLUMN password password VARCHAR(856) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';`

Comment: @Pasha wow I umm this is awkward and weird.. didnt know that worked? Problem is now solved. Thanks I guess. Cant upvote you thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the type of you column to VARCHAR(512) which will allow you to store more than 255 chars in your column (actually 512). It is possible to use value from 1 to 8000 there or VARCHAR(MAX) for biggest one (in situations when data entries length vary a lot).

In you case, try something like this:

```
`ALTER TABLE name_of_your_table 
 CHANGE COLUMN password password VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';`
```